# How to fetch apk itself from the google play store using PHP script?

Tags: php, google-play, apk

Hey guys i have this project which needs to download APK file directly from google play store to the PC using an PHP script. I have looked into the python script which is very old and doesn't work now. I see sites like apkpure.com and apk-dl are doing it.

I have used google play link **scraper** Link to **scrape** the application details from google play store. But i can't figure out a way to get the application itself from google play.
Can anyone guide me in a right direction for this?
Really appreciate it guys.
Thanks.

The link **scraper** that i use only fetch the application information not the application itself. I also looked into chrome extensions like some of you suggested but they don't hold the answer that i require. Please suggest something else.